# GLPK OpenBLAS runtime dll link error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, armadillo, glpk, openblas

I have a program written using Armadillo C++ linked to OpenBLAS and also GLPK.

It compiles and links properly in both Debug and Release under VS2010 using identical libraries. It runs perfectly in Debug, just slowly.

The Release binary emits the following error:

> The procedure entry point glp_get_num_cols could not be located in the dynamic link library libopenblas.dll.

Any ideas on where to start with this? I have confirmed that the configuration for Debug and Release are identical with the exception of debug symbols allowed in the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libopenblas.dll was the cause of the problem - for some reason linking in VS2010 caused errors. I am not sure why, but linking against the lapack libraries in the Armadillo distribution (pre v4) fixed the issue.